# video doesnot play but audio listening

Tags: android, video, android-emulator

```
public class video extends Activity {

    @Override       
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.surface);
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
        // Set video link (mp4 format )
        Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() +"/"+R.raw.wildlife);
        Intent tostart = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        startActivity(tostart);
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        videoView.setVideoURI(video);
        videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.start();
    }
}
```

here is my code to play the video. But the video stays in my screen and it does not play. Is there any solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
video_player_view.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<VideoView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/VideoPlayerView" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/> 


Java code:

 public class VideoPlayerActivity extends Activity {


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.video_player_view);


        String video_file_path = ?;//give the path of your video

        VideoView video_view = (VideoView) this.findViewById(R.id.VideoPlayerView); 
        MediaController mc = new MediaController(this); 
        video_view.setMediaController(mc); 
        video_view.setVideoPath(video_file_path);  
        video_view.requestFocus(); 

        // start video 
        video_view.start();

        video_view.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {


            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                endActivity();
            }
    });



    }
    public void endActivity() {
        this.finish();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using this code?

```
Intent tostart = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
startActivity(tostart);
```

If it is not necessary then remove it video will be played with sound. Otherwise please write what you exactly want to do with video playback.